# Get Firestore Data in Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Angular project and I try to get data from a Firestore-Database. With my code, I get all documents with 4 fields of my collection "profiles". It is clear to me, because I use a for-loop in the html-document.

But now I would like to get only the first document with 4 fields. I tried different things, but I always get an error.
[Firestore-Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvhv8.png)

Code in component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profilemain',
  templateUrl: './profilemain.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profilemain.component.css'],
})
export class ProfilemainComponent implements OnInit {
  profile: Profile[] | undefined;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Init');
    this.afs
      .collection<Profile>('profiles')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((values: any) => {
        console.log(values);
        this.profile = values;
      });
  }
}
```

Code in component.html

```html
<app-profileheader></app-profileheader>
<body class="profile">
  <div *ngIf="profile">
    <div *ngFor="let profile of profile">
      <h1 class="topic">{{ profile.topic }}</h1>
      <h2 class="name">{{ profile.name }}</h2>
      <h2 class="location">{{ profile.location }}</h2>
      <p class="description">{{ profile.description }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How can I do this?

Many thanks & best regards,
Sarah